# Finding How to Transform a Plane to Reflect a Trajectory through a Given Coordinate

Tags: kinematics, collision, projectile

So, for context, I am trying to analyze how this basketball machine works:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FycDx69px8U

I have a basic understanding of how to calculate the new velocity of the ball after colliding with the backboard (assuming an elastic collision), but how would I approach finding a transform for the plane representing the backboard if I have a coordinate that the resulting trajectory should pass through?

In other words, given an incoming trajectory and a desired resulting trajectory after a collision, how would I find the plane (or normal vector representing that plane) that would create that resulting desired trajectory?

If there isn't a direct mathematical way to solve this, would I just sequence the different planes the trajectory can collide with and find one that fits a given set of parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we assume that during the collision, the plane only exerts a force on the ball that perpendicular to the plane itself ($\vec{F} \propto \hat{n}$), then the impulse delivered $\int \vec{F} \, dt = \Delta \vec{p} = m \Delta \vec{v}$ will also perpendicular to the plane.  Thus, for a given $\vec{v}_f $ and $\vec{v}_i$, the normal to the plane $\hat{n}$ must point in the same direction as $\vec{v}_f - \vec{v}_i$.

Note, however, that it is possible for a surface to exert a force on the ball that is not strictly perpendicular to its surface.  This happens, for example, when we throw a ball with a fair amount of "spin".  I suspect this can be precluded by assuming that the ball does not have significant angular momentum, but I don't see an easy proof of this.

Comment: Alright, so I would solve for the plane as follows? 
$\vec{n} = \frac{(\vec{v}_f - \vec{v}_i)}{(\lVert(\vec{v}_f - \vec{v}_i)\rVert)}$

Where $\vec{n} $ is the normal of the plane.

If so, is there an equation to transform the plane to match that normal?

Comment: @BrandonMichelsen:  Yes, if you want $\hat{n}$ to be a unit normal vector.  As far as how to "transform the plane", I'm not entirely sure what you mean by that, but it sounds like more of a question for [Math.SE] than for this forum.

Comment: Got it, I'll ask about the transform there. Also, just to clarify, the method we discussed for finding $\hat{n}$ given $\vec{v}_f$ and $\vec{v}_i$ will work for any trajectory defined by $\vec{v}_i$, correct? In other words, it will work for any angle the trajectory approaches from?

Comment: @BrandonMichelsen: the only time the formula won't work is when the two vectors are the same. But then you don't need to deflect the ball anyway.

Comment: Got it. Now, one last question. If I don't know $\vec{v}_f$ but I know I want the trajectory defined by $\vec{v}_f$ to pass through a given coordinate and I have a starting coordinate, how would I find $\vec{v}_f$?

Comment: @BrandonMichelsen: That's probably more complicated than I can answer in comments. I would recommend you read up on projectile motion (an introductory calculus-based university physics textbook should be enough to get you started) and then post further questions if you're still having trouble.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for your help!